# Extract field using Python

Tags: python

I am looking for help to extract one specific field.

Here is the example, I am not able to split and cut based on field number because number may change due to the content change

**Example 1**

```
[["cn","Phone",1,"","LI(\"\")","0","19%","",""],["OS_DisplayName","Display Name",1,"","LI(\"\")","1,0","19%","",""],["OS_ProductPackage","Product Package",1,"","CO(\"\",\"REQ;1_BASIC!OS!TRV;2_Messaging!OS!OEM;3_Extended!OS!EAC;4_Enhanced!OS!APO;5_Analog Port!OS!CCA;6_Contact Center Agent\",\"\",\";\",\"\",\"\")","2,0","19%","",""],["sn","Last name",1,"","LI(\"\")","3,0","12%","",""],["givenName","First name",1,"","LI(\"\")","4,0","12%","",""],["OS_SiteCode","Site Code",1,"","LI(\"\")","5,0","19%","",""]],[["917845678923","Backup","OEM","917845678923","","CNdd_RD_91784567","","cn=917845678923,cn=Subscribers,cn=np_CNdd_RnD_WangJing,cn=IPC_APAC_1_01,cn=DN,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OS"]],
```

Output should be

```
cn=917845678923,cn=Subscribers,cn=np_CNdd_RnD_WangJing,cn=IPC_APAC_1_01,cn=DN,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OS
```

**Example 2**

```
[["cn","Phone",1,"","LI(\"\")","0","19%","",""],["OS_DisplayName","Display Name",1,"","LI(\"\")","1,0","19%","",""],["OS_ProductPackage","Product Package",1,"","CO(\"\",\"REQ;1_BASIC!OS!TRV;2_Messaging!OS!OEM;3_Extended!OS!EAC;4_Enhanced!OS!APO;5_Analog Port!OS!CCA;6_Contact Center Agent\",\"\",\";\",\"\",\"\")","2,0","19%","",""],["sn","Last name",1,"","LI(\"\")","3,0","12%","",""],["givenName","First name",1,"","LI(\"\")","4,0","12%","",""],["OS_SiteCode","Site Code",1,"","LI(\"\")","5,0","19%","",""]],[["868694755000","Yaeng Danning","EAC","Yaeng","Dainning","CNdd_DT_86869475","","cn=868694755000,cn=Subscribers,cn=np_CNdd_DN,cn=IPC_APAC_1_01,cn=DN,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OS"]],
```

**Output should be**

```
cn=868694755000,cn=Subscribers,cn=np_CNdd_DN,cn=IPC_APAC_1_01,cn=DN,cn=Resources,cn=Users,cn=OS
```

Can someone help me on this.

i tried below code but i am not able to use constant filed number (e[8]) due to field number change

```
    e = line3.split('","","')
    print "e"
    print e
    e = e[8].replace('"]],','').replace('","','').strip()
    print "e:" ,e
```

Comment: `e = line3.split('","","')`

 `print e`
  `e = e[8].replace('"]],','').replace('","','').strip()`  
  `print "e:" ,e`

Comment: please edit your post - comments are not the right place for code.

Comment: i tried this and it was working now i cannot use constant field number, you can see the field numbers are changing.

Answer (score 2):

You could flatten the list and then search through it.

```
myList = (['one', 'two', ['cn=blahblah', 4, [5],['hi']], [6, [[[7, 'hello']]]]])

def flatten(container):
  for i in container:
    if isinstance(i, (list,tuple)):
      for j in flatten(i):
        yield j
    else:
      yield i

flattenedList = list(flatten(myList))

for x in flattenedList:
  if str(x).startswith('cn='):
    print(x)
```

Comment: could you please give me one example

Comment: i wrote you the working code... you should just put your list inside the variable named "myList", that will be flattened to a simple one dimensional list that you can parse with a simple loop.

Comment: but when i tried my flattenedList printing link below                                         `['[', '[', '"', 'c', 'n', '"', ',', '"', 'P', 'h', 'o', 'n', 'e', '"', ',', '1', ',', '"', '"', ',', '"', 'L', 'I', '(', '\\', '"', '\\', '"', ')', '"', ',', '"', '0', '"', ',', '"', '1', '9', '%', '"', ',', '"', '"', ',', '"', '"', ']', ',', '[', '"', 'O', 'S', 'I', 'L', 'A', '_', 'D', 'i', 's', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y', 'N', 'a', 'm', 'e', '"', ',', '"', 'D', 'i', 's', 'p', 'l', 'a', 'y', ' ', 'N', 'a', 'm', 'e', '"', ',', '1', ',', '"', '"', ',', '"',`

Comment: Enclose your list between parenthesis to define it... for example: myList = ([["cn","Phone",1,"", ..............  =Users,cn=OS"]])

Answer (score 1):

If you are guaranteed the `cn` field is the very last, you could do something like:

```
cnFields = array [-1][-1]
```

and then parse it as you see fit.

Otherwise, you'll need to iterate through the 2d array until you find a string that starts with `cn=`.

Comment: `>>> b = s [-1][-1]`
`>>> sd = b [+7]`
`>>> print sd`      this working for me can we use it in single line